# How do I close a window I opened after it loads with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way for me to open a link in a new window after it loads?

I have tried these two methods, but the windows won't close itself.

Method 1:

```
var winning = window.open("https://google.com/","","width=500,height=500");
winning.onload = function(){
  winning.close();
}:
```

Method 2:

```
var winning = window.open("https://google.com/","","width=500,height=500");
winning.addEventListener('onload', function(){
  winning.close();
}, false);
```

I'm kind of going insane over this. Am I missing something obvious, or is this simply impossible?

Comment: Is your event listener firing?  If you log to the console as the first line, does it log?

Comment: Is the event called 'load' and not 'onload'? I don't see onload listed on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: @StephenCrosby — The event is called `load` the property used to directly access an event handler for it is called `onload`. Prefixing with `on` is a standard pattern. (Oh, you meant in Method 2, I was looking at Method 1)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill It doesn't log to the console with both 'onload' or 'load'

Comment: You can not close a window that is in a different domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bumping into the same Same Origin Policy. You can't capture `load` events on documents on a different origin (because it tells you that the page successfully loaded, which can leak information like "The user is logged into this site which would otherwise throw a Forbidden error").

If I change the URL to one with the same origin as the page in which the JavaScript appears, then it works.

The closest you can come to this is to estimate how long it would take for the document to load and use `setTimeout` to close it.

Comment: @epascarello I was able to close the window with a `setTimeout`. Nevermind! I realized I did it in a hacky way. Opened a blank window and changed the location to the link I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* attach an event listener to another window, but *only* if both windows are on the same domain/protocol/port.

[Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) limits the properties and events you can access cross-origin, and unlike a `iframe` (which fires a `load` event of it's own you can listen to), you cannot attach a `load` event listener to a window created with `window.open` unless they satisfy Same-Origin Policy.

---

Also, on a side note, this is a typo:

```
winning.addEventListener('onload', function(){
```

Should be:

```
winning.addEventListener('load', function(){
```

You don't include the `on` prefix when using `addEventListener`.